# ...Is null and never assigned to, but it looks like it does get assigned?

Tags: c#, class, null

I am trying to populate a DataGridView (datagridviewCustomers) with a table from SQL. Below is my code from the form with the DataGridView, and beneath that is a class that connects to the database (SqlHelper.cs) and has other functions that I use throughout my program so I don't have to keep re-writing the code on each form.

My DataTable that gets data from SQL is called dtCustomers1 and is used as the datasource for my DataGridView. MS Visual Studio tells me that dtCustomers1 is "never assigned to, and will always have its default value null."

dtCustomers2, however, does not show this error and works properly, filling the DataGridView. dtCustomers2 is another DataTable that functions just like dtCustomers1, although it does not use the SqlHelper.cs class.

I created dtCustomers2 to try the code from SqlHelper.cs on the form to see if there was something wrong with the SqlHelper.cs code, but it seems to be working fine when it's on the same form...

Can any one see why this is happening? What am I missing in the code for dtCustomers1 / populateCustomersTable() that is causing this value to be never assigned??

```
namespace X.FormName
{
    sqlDBConnect con; //see sqlHelper.cs below for this class
    DataTable dtCustomers1;

    public FormName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        populateCustomerTable(); //uses code from sqlHelper.cs 
        getCustomerTable(); //uses only the code from this form
    }

    //using sqlHelper.cs and dtCustomers1
    private void populateCustomerTable()
    {
        con = new sqlDBConnect();
        con.sqlQuery
            (
                "SELECT * FROM dbo.customer"
            );
        con.fetchDT(dtCustomers1);
        datagridviewCustomers.DataSource = dtCustomers1;
    }

    // using only code shown below and dtCustomers2
    private void getCustomerTable()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"DATA CONNECTION STRING");

        DataTable dtCustomers2 = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.customer", con);
        sda.Fill(dtCustomers2);
        tableCustomers.DataSource = dtCustomers2;

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Below is sqlHelper.cs

```
namespace X
{
    public class sqlDBConnect
    {
        private SqlConnection _con;
        public SqlCommand cmd;
        private SqlDataAdapter _sda;

        public sqlDBConnect()
        {
            _con = new SqlConnection(@"DATA CONNECTION STRING");
            _con.Open();
        }

        public void sqlQuery(string queryText)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, _con);
        }

        public void fetchDT(DataTable currentDataTable)
        {
            _sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            currentDataTable = new DataTable();
            _sda.Fill(currentDataTable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's confusing that you have a member variable called dtCustomers2, **and** a local variable also called dtCustomers2 in getCustomerTable.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post to provide minimal sample... (Also I'm afraid you'll lose reason to ask question on SO when you do that... may not be too bad as post in current form likely collect downvotes in addition to close votes for "no MCVE")

Comment: That was just a mistake from when I was trying to move the code - it shouldn't be there. dtCustomers2 isn't the problem, though. As far as those guidelines, M: I did restart from scratch and rebuilt this in a new program. C: It is complete... that's all there is in the second program. V: I'm not just saying "it doesn't work." I'm asking if anyone can see what is going wrong with populateCustomersTable. As I have made this code in a brand new app and the problem happens again for me, it "Ensure[s] that the example actually reproduces the problem!"

Comment: Based on the code you posted, you should be getting warnings for both `dtCustomers1` and `dtCustomers2`. The first, the warning you're getting (i.e. will always have the value `null`), the second, a warning that the field is never used. The code you posted can work with `dtCustomers2`, because it never tries to use that field. If that difference is not relevant to your question, you need to provide a good [mcve] that shows _exactly_ what's going on. There's too much ambiguity here at the moment.

Comment: Ambiguity? What can I do to make it less ambiguous? And isn't the field being used? The table is being filled in both cases.

Comment: _"What can I do to make it less ambiguous?"_ -- the answer to that question can be found in the article [mcve], which I provided the link for in my previous comment. See also [ask] for more advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. _"isn't the field being used?"_ -- no, it's not. The only identifier `dtCustomers2` which you actually use is that of a local variable that _hides_ the field having the same name. The field having that name is never used.